# Button to switch between front and back camera in my camera app in android studio and face detection

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, face-detection

I'm developping a camera app on android studio using openCv 3.0.0.It's my first time doing this and I'm facing some problems. But I have 2 issues:
1) I want to add a button to switch between the front camera and the back camera. But I can't seem to find a way to switch.

Here is my onCreate method:

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private static int number = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view);

     // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance(number);// This funtion opens the camera

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, number , mCamera);
        final FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        preview.addView(mPreview);


        // Add a listener to the Capture button
        ImageButton captureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image captured!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // get an image from the camera
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                }
        );

// Add a listener to the Change button
        ImageButton changeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_change);
        changeButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (number == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                            number = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
                        else
                            number = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
                       //HERE SHOULD BE THE STEPS TO SWITCH
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // get an image from the camera

                    }
                }
        ); 
}
```

2)I want to use openCv for face detection on the image that's captures but I don't know whether it's possible. I couldn't find anything on the web. I've already tried the example faceDetect from openCv 3.0.0 and it worked when I was using the camera. That's what I wanted to do at first but after I changed my layout to contain a frame layout instead of org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView it doesn't work anymore. So if anyone has an idea why I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ***CameraView** classes have **disableView** and **enableView** methods. You need to disable view, set mCameraIndex field of View object and enable view again. **mCameraView** is protected method, so the only solution is to implement view subclass and setters/getters. See **tutorial-3** example for more details.

```
<org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view"
            android:layout_width="350px"
            android:layout_height="350px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            opencv:camera_id="front" />
```

Comment: Does this solution concern face detection or the button switch? I've already seen the tutorial-3 example. But I couldn't add face detection in it. That's why I moved on.

Comment: It will give you the brief idea about the camera swicthing

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been of great help. I did what you told me and the switch is working just fine. Even the face detection worked.